# IE10: How to get mouse coordinates on dragover

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

In IE 10 when the event ondragover is fired the values of the attributes clientX, clientY, pageX, pageY, don't seem to be refreshed when the mouse is moved. Webkit browsers and Firefox accurately updates the mouse coordinates.

Simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#log').on('dragover', function(e) {
        $('#log').text(e.originalEvent.pageX + " | " + e.originalEvent.pageY);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kristoffer/kCZmg/

Is there a workaround for IE10?

Comment: Terrible support from MS does *not* address a solution but does confirm it is not an uncommon problem:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/36e93551-c9b0-48aa-9b16-154cbc2d2d17/ie-10-dragover-event-clientx-clienty-pagex-pagey-datatransfergetdata-are-not-refreshed?forum=iewebdevelopment&prof=required

Comment: even better, IE10 entirely suppresses mousemove events until the drag operation is over, so you can't even capture the coördinates elsewhere and use them that way. as far as i can tell there is no workaround. the offsetX/Y values do change, but mostly nonsensically. and clientX/Y do actually change, but only by about a millionth of a pixel. quite odd.